# Не могу запустить скачанный код node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Загрузил код приложения с githab'а и не могу запустить у себя на компе.

[image: Module not found, JS]

Answer (score 1):

Интерпретатор ругается на отсутствие модуля, скорее всего его ссылка изменилась.

Вам необходимо запустить консоль и написать в ней node -v, если будет написано, что "node не является системной командой", то необходимо переустановить NodeJS и добавить PATH в реестр.
Если же после команды node -v вам показывает версию установленного NodeJS, то вероятнее всего как я сказал выше - проблема в самом скрипте.

Так же, вы можете удалить всё содержимое запускаемого вами файла (в вашем случаи server.js) и написать в нем console.log('hello'). Если в консоли вы увидите слово Hello, то всё работает корректно и проблема в скрипте, которые вы скачали.

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня и другие проекты ругаются "Module not found" как проверить исправность подключать другие файлы к проекту?

Comment: Я у вас не увидел папки `node_modules` в проекте. Перед запуском скаченного проекта вы устанавливали его зависимости (пакеты)? Если нет, то вам необходимо написать `npm install` в консоле.

Comment: Я уже открыл новый проект создал папку package.json и установил все зависимости командой npm install(все зависимости добавились). Папка 'node_modules' присутствует

Comment: При вводе команды `node -v` в терминале выводится версия `nodejs`?

Comment: Спасибо я уже разобрался, проблемы, как вы и говорили, были в самом скрипте и в моей криворукости, спасибо за помощь ^^

Comment: @РомаДовгалюк, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)